# Form_tag submit rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

So I have been working on a web application with ruby on rails. I have form tags on my home page but when I click submit it fails to save the information to a guest or current user (I'm using devise) and redirect to a different page. The app isn't giving me any errors, it just won't take in the information. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
    class PageController < ApplicationController
  def home
    unless @button.nil?
      @location = Place.create(:address => params[:place], :phone_number  => params[:phone], :name  => params[:title], :status => "not_purchased", :user_id => current_or_guest_user.id)
      @location.save!
      if @location.save && !@location.address.nil?
        redirect_to places_path
      end
    end
  end

  def index
  end


  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @location }
    end
  end

  def new
  end


  def create
    unless @button.nil?
      @location = Place.create(:address => params[:place], :phone_number  => params[:phone], :name  => params[:title], :status => "not_purchased", :user_id => current_or_guest_user.id)
      @location.save!
      if @location.save
        format.html { redirect_to places_path}
        format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: places_path }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def map
  end



end
```

page/home.html.erb

```
<section id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="wrapper row-1">
        <div class="box col-1 maxheight">
          <div class="border-right maxheight">
            <div class="border-bot maxheight">
              <div class="border-left maxheight">
                <div class="left-top-corner maxheight">
                  <div class="right-top-corner maxheight">
                    <div class="right-bot-corner maxheight">
                      <div class="left-bot-corner maxheight">
                        <div class="inner">
                          <h3>Check Availability</h3>
                          <section style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 10px; margin:10px">
                            <h5>Add your site(s)</h5>
                            <b><%= field_set_tag '' do %> </b>
                                  <%= form_tag do %>
                                      <p>
                                        <%= label_tag 'title', "Name of Site"%>
                                        <%= text_field_tag 'title', nil, :placeholder => "Enter your site name", :size => 40%><br/>
                                      </p>
                                      <p>
                                        <%= label_tag 'place', "Address"%>
                                        <%= text_field_tag 'place', nil, :placeholder => "Enter your  address", :size => 40%><br/>
                                      </p>
                                      <p>
                                        <%= label_tag 'phone', "Phone number"%>
                                        <%= text_field_tag 'phone', nil, :placeholder => "Enter your phone number", :size => 40%><br/>
                                      </p>
                                      <p><span><span><%=@button = submit_tag "Add me!", data: {:confirm => "Are you sure?"}%></span></span></p>
                                  <% end %>
                              <% end %>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get rid of that `field_set_tag` before your form. Not sure what that purpose is since you're not passing anything to it.

Then in your form_tag add this :

```
<%= form_tag @location do %>
```

Where @location is the object the form is about.

Also remove from your home controller this :

```
 @location = Place.create(:address => params[:place], :phone_number  => params[:phone], :name  => params[:title], :status => "not_purchased", :user_id => current_or_guest_user.id)
  @location.save!
```

You're not creating it there. You're creating it in in your `create` action. So instead in your #home action just instantiate what `@location` is :

```
 @location = Place.new user_id: current_or_guest_user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In your page/home.html.erb view, `form_tag` requires a URL that points to a controller action. Its blank ATM so its defaulting to a POST action, but it's not posting to anything. Try:

```
<%= form_tag @location do %>
```

Additionally, that @button instance variable is always going to be equal to nil as it doesn't seem to be initialized anywhere.